# can't download apps after "authorizing computer"

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, applications

I recently synced my iPod touch(4th gen) for the first time and it asked me if I wanted to "authorize the computer"- I chose "yes" but now, I can't download apps(neither from my ipod nor from the computer). It asks for credit card info. but since I don't have a credit card, now I can't download apps(free ones) at all.

Deauthorizing doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534) procedure to create an iTunes App Store account without a credit card.

Comment: @Rob- Thanks, it worked. I had already created an account but selecting None in the card type helped in the verification too. :)